# Visual Sudio - MSAccess Database. Delete fails. Ideas please

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Using the code below, the operations is successful  visually, but the deletion does not hold when the page is rerun.
Any ideas would be appreciated!
I dont think the dataset name needs to reflect the bindingsource and tableadapters.

```
Private Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Click

        If Me.EnableEditingCheckbox.Checked Then

            If Me.AddNewButton.Text = "Cancel" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If Not DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Try

                    Dim result As DialogResult

                    result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to permantely DELETE the selected record?", "DELETION Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

                    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then

                        Me.TTimeBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
                        Me.TTimeBindingSource.EndEdit()
                        Me.TTimeTableAdapter.Update(Me.DocketMV4DataSet.tTime)




                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Access Denied!" & Environment.NewLine & "You need permission to perform this action" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "Please contact the programmer or ask Google!", "Delete operation failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
                Return
                '  Exit Sub
            End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you defined a primary key field in table? If yes, an alternative method uses SQL.

Comment: When you say the delete fails, are you getting some exception?  I see you're catching exceptions but not doing anything with it.  Maybe in you're catch MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())

Comment: Hursey, In my forms, I see the action and the deletion, but when I reload, the record is still there, as well as when I open the database.

Comment: June27. I do have a primary key, but I am trying to stay away from SQL, as my knowledge is very limited,  and just use the objects in VB.

Comment: DELETE action is simple SQL. If you want to consider, review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/183e6cd2-b9dc-47ad-9e90-e6c15f2738fc/removecurrent-only-delete-data-on-datagridview-not-in-access-database

Comment: June7 - I had a look, I will definitely be spending more hours on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done stuff in Acccess but Your message box use is different than what I typically use.

This worked for me just now in a test.

```
Dim result
result = MsgBox("Do you want to permantely DELETE the selected record?", vbYesNo, "Delete Confirm")
If result = vbYes Then
    MsgBox (" do your stuff")
    Me.TTimeBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    Me.TTimeBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TTimeTableAdapter.Update (Me.DocketMV4DataSet.tTime)
Else
    MsgBox ("Don't Do your stuff")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, Must be that nagging in the back of my head....bad data connection.  MANY THANKS